# Filtering the displayed json data based on an array in Angular 7

Tags: angular, filter, drop-down-menu, dropdown, angular7

I receive json data from the backend using a service and I'm displaying it through a loop in main.html. Now there is an array which consists the values of a column that is being displayed. 
Let's say the array looks like this, colors=[red,blue]. Then I want only the records with red and blue color to be displayed.

**main.html**

```
<div  class="flip-right" *ngFor="let items of obs | async">
 <mat-card>
   <mat-card-header>
       <mat-card-title>{{items.name}}</mat-card-title>
   </mat-card-header>
   <mat-card-subtitle>{{items.color}} </mat-card-subtitle>

 </mat-card>
</div>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

**main.ts**

```
   export class PrivateComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
        //filter variables to store the selected values
        color=[red,blue];


        subscription: Subscription;

      @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;


      obs: Observable<any>;
      dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

      constructor(
        private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
        private cardsInfo :CardsInfoService) { 



    }

      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        if (this.dataSource) { 
          this.dataSource.disconnect(); 
        }
      }
      ngOnInit(){
        this.cardsInfo.getCardsInfo()
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.dataSource.data = data;
          });


          this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.obs = this.dataSource.connect();


      }


      ngAfterViewInit() {

        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }



    }
```

**json data that is being passed through the service**

```
[
   {"id":"1","name":"abc","color":"red"},
{"id":"2","name":"def","color":"blue"},
{"id":"3","name":"ghi","color":"green"},
{"id":"4","name":"def","color":"yellow"},
{"id":"5","name":"xyz","color":"red"},
  ]
```

Here, I only want the red and blue color to be displayed.

Comment: Can you provide StackBlitz

Comment: For some reason, I'm unable to reproduce the code. Basically what I want to achieve is, I have two arrays in component and I want to filter the dataSource based on the values of the array.

Comment: Ok but two arrays and you waNt to filter data from array1

Comment: No, there are two arrays which consists of selected values from two multi select drop downs. I want to filter the data displayed in mat-card based on the selected values from both the arrays.

Comment: Do u want to combine the two array? That is selected1 array and selected2 array?

Comment: No. Both the array consists of values of different columns that is being displayed. I want to filter the data displayed based on the value selected in the arrays. I think i have confused you by telling there are two arrays. Let's say there is only one array which looks like this  array1=[red, blue, green] then i want to display only the rows with these colors.

Comment: Now it's clear! Just edit your  question with these two arrays with some sample data, will try

Comment: I edited the question now! @PrashantPimpale

Comment: Have posted an answer check once!

Comment: Do you want this `{ "id": "5", "name": "xyz", "color": "red" }` object also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for-loop on the `array1` [array on which you want to check is that color is available or not] and then check for is that color is available in the destination array, so the code will be:

TS code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic list
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'list-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'list-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['list-overview-example.css'],
})
export class ListOverviewExample {

  array1: any[] = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

  originalArray = [
    { "id": "1", "name": "abc", "color": "red" },
    { "id": "2", "name": "def", "color": "blue" },
    { "id": "3", "name": "ghi", "color": "green" },
    { "id": "4", "name": "def", "color": "yellow" },
    { "id": "5", "name": "xyz", "color": "red" },
  ]
  filteredArray: any[] = [];

  constructor() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.array1.length; i++) {
      var list = this.originalArray.filter(x => x.color == this.array1[i]);
      list.forEach(x => {
        this.filteredArray.push(x);
      })
    }
    console.log(this.filteredArray)
  }
}
```

[`Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/filter-array-from-another-array)

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I was looking for, but however i ran to a problem. I receive data from the backend api through a service and I have declared  "dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();" to use mat-paginator. Because of this, I'm unable to use some,push and find methods. Is there any way around this?

Comment: yes after this filter array just add the dataSource and other property to it

Comment: If possible, can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Hey, that still didn't work. I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/filter-array-from-another-array-vqgtu3) of how I'm displaying the data. Can you please help me how to add your integrate your logic in this?

Comment: Sure give me some time!

Comment: Yeah. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have done with sample JSON API, check out here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/filter-array-from-another-array-with-http-get

Comment: @niveshK.E its a normal get api so i have used this

Comment: It works! But again one small issue, it displays only the first instance of the ids. Lets say in my json data "id":"1" is repeated 5 times, but your code displays only the first instance of "id":"1" and neglects the remaining 4 records.

Comment: yup! Just use `filter` instead `find`

Comment: @niveshK.E you dont also need that if condition, I removed and updated the answer

Comment: I ran into another problem, what if the array which we're using to filter the data gets updated dynamically? How to refresh the subscription in that case? Or can we filter the data outside the subscription?